# Lock excel cell with conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have been dealing with small issue. I got an VBA code which won't work on cells that have conditional formatting. Is there a way to fix it? What I need to achieve is that cell would be locked after automatic input from device. If it is between correct measurements it would be painted green. So I wrote an VBA code that locks cells and it worked fine until I tried on range that has conditional formatting.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cel As Range
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ' Password:="2020"
For Each cel In Target
    If cel.Value <> "" Then
        cel.Locked = True
    End If
Next cel
ActiveSheet.Protect ' Password:="2020"
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually `ActiveSheet.Unprotect`  must be `Me.Unprotect`. Active sheet is not necessarily the same sheet as where `Target` is in. • Additionally clarify what *"… which won't work on …"* means. *"Does not work"* is a completely useless error description. • Finally I cannot reproduce your issue, so please be more precise how exactly your conditional formatting looks like. Provide a [mcve] to reproduce it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I agree with `Me` but I can't think of a scenario where `ActiveSheet` would be something else, can you think of one?

Comment: @BigBen yes, any procedure changing a value in a cell of a sheet that is not active while the procedure runs. Eg Sheet1 has that change event and sheet2 is active then you run a code `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 5`.

Comment: Ah yes that would be an instance yeah, I was only thinking of manual changes by the end user.

Comment: @BigBen Since OP spoke about *"after automatic input from device"* I guessed there was no manual but automatic input of the values?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ :facepalm: too early in the morning, I need to read more thoroughly :-)

Comment: Anyway I cannot reproduce the issue. If I put your code on a new sheet and put a conditinal formatting rule it works without issues.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I added the sample excel file. If I try to input in E:P columns it will lock and won't unlock automatically anymore.

Comment: @LukasŠliužas sorry but macro enabled files from a suspect source will probably not be downloaded by anyone. Actually that is why uploding files is not supported on Stack Overflow. Everything that is needed to understand your question need to be in the text of the question itself (see [ask]). • As I said already: I took a new file, added a conditional formatting, set all cells to not locked and used your code several times without issues. So please explain (in your question, not a comment) what you have done to make it fail. Reproduce it starting from a plain sheet step by step.